# Xubuntu doesn't always connect wirelessly

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, xubuntu, atheros

Sometimes when I boot up Xubuntu 15.10, I can't connect to my wireless network. Sometimes I can view other networks that are in range and sometimes I can't, but in these instances I can't connect to my own Wi-Fi. Restarting Xubuntu usually does the trick, but sometimes I have to restart two or three times for it to work. How can I fix this so that my computer connects automatically every time I boot?

I have XUbuntu 15.10 64-bit installed on a 
 Lenovo Z50-70 Laptop.
 
**Specs:**
  Atheros AR9565 On-board wireless adapter
 Intel Core i7-4510U
 8GB DDR3 RAM
 1TB HDD

As a related issue, most of the time when I boot up and I *can* connect to Wi-Fi, Dropbox doesn't sync and my VPN program (VPN Unlimited) won't automatically log me in.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed this in recent Ubuntu releases (15.04 notably).  Have you had a look at Launchpad, e.g.:

- [Bug #767423 “NetworkManager does not show available access point...” : Bugs : network-manager package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/767423).
- [Bug #1332904 “Network manager stopped scanning for wifi networks...” : Bugs : network-manager package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1332904)

I usually do `sudo iwlist scan` as a workaround.

Comment: Hi Stéphane, thank you for your answer. The next time I have this problem (hasn't happened today), I will give `sudo iwlist scan` a try.